# Linq to SQL: GroupBy() and Max() to get set of data

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Consider a table with the following schema

[Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNEMe.jpg)

I would like to fetch data from each Status where category is max

1. In '1' Status, max category is 2, so fetch all rows of category 2
2. In '2' Status, max category is null, so fetch all rows of category null

[Expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O70kF.jpg)

I need help in creating a linq query to fetch the above data.

I tried a few ways but couldnt get what I wanted. Below is one of the example.

```
var tableData = (from d in x.Data
                 group d by d.Status into grp
                 select new { Status = grp.Key, Category = grp.Max(d => d.Category) }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close, your current code selects all the statues & their max categories. Now you just need to rejoin on that

```cs
var maxCategories = (from d in x.Data
                 group d by d.Status into grp
                 select new { Status = grp.Key, Category = grp.Max(d => d.Category) });

var tableData = (from d in x.Data
                         join mc in maxCategories on new { d.Status, d.Category } equals new { mc.Status, mc.Category }
                         select new { Id = d.Id, Status = d.Status, Category = d.Category })
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: unfortunately, I kept getting syntax error which I couldn't understand or find a solution to fix it. Thanks for helping @itsdaniel0

Comment: There was a syntax error, updated now